# Check if the element is created or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code,

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="shipment-filter">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-table="ShipmentsDataTable" id="exportShipmentCSV_all"> CSV - All Shipments </a>
</div>
```

And based on that, I want to add an anchor element before `#exportShipmentCSV_all`.

Here's what I did.

```
let newElementA = document.createElement('a');
newElementA.setAttribute('id', 'classfilterBtnIsClicked');
newElementA.dataset.classfilterBtnIsClicked = true;

let currentDiv  = document.getElementById('shipment-filter');
currentDiv.insertBefore(newElementA, currentDiv.childNodes[0]);
```

After doing that,

If the `#exportShipmentCSV_all` has been clicked, I'd like to check if the element exists using this way

```
if (document.getElementById('classfilterBtnIsClicked').length) {
    // Code here
}
```

which is based on this reference.
[Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

But doing so, I got this error in chrome dev tool console.tab

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Within this code, there are also jquery in it,

Can you suggest the way I should check, if element has been created or not?

Comment: You need to check `null` when using Vanilla JS i.e. `if(document.getElementById('classfilterBtnIsClicked') !== null){//Your code}`

Answer (score 0):

[Document.getElementById() - Return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Return_value)

> An Element object describing the DOM element object matching the specified ID, or null if no matching element was found in the document.

The returned element object does not have *length* property, thus you get *undefined*.

Why use *length*? You do not need to use *length* property here, checking the element object itself is enough:

```js
let newElementA = document.createElement('a');
newElementA.setAttribute('id', 'classfilterBtnIsClicked');
newElementA.dataset.classfilterBtnIsClicked = true;

let currentDiv  = document.getElementById('shipment-filter');
currentDiv.insertBefore(newElementA, currentDiv.childNodes[0]);

if (document.getElementById('classfilterBtnIsClicked')) {
    console.log('Element exists');
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="shipment-filter">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-table="ShipmentsDataTable" id="exportShipmentCSV_all"> CSV - All Shipments </a>
</div>
```